# User can delete root-owned files in their home directory, or What are the rules controlling altering files inside of user-writable directories?

Tags: linux, permissions

Try this code

```
root /home/user $ touch hehehe
```

then as a normal user

```
user ~ $ rm -f hehehe
```

Our user can remove a root-owned file inside of their home directory.  This works not only in their home directory, but inside of any directory writable by them.

Now try

```
root /home/user $ mkdir -p testdir
```

and

```
user ~ $ rm -rf testdir
```

Works too.  However:

```
root /home/user $ mkdir -p testdir/childdir
user ~ $ rm -rf testdir/childdir
```

fails, so our user apparently cannot delete non-empty non-writable directories inside writable directories.

By my understanding, all three of these test cases should have failed.  But apparently when a directory is writable, that endows a user with some non-trivial capabilities with regard to its contents.

What are the exact rules regarding which of the primitive filesystem operations (`create`, `delete`, etc.)` may be performed with respect to the filesystem permissions that a user has?

Comment: You have write access for a directory you can remove entries from it. In your latest example you would try to remove a directory from a directory where you don't have write access and as such it fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answers become very clear, once you understand that in all UNIX-compatible file systems a file is **not** something that lives inside a directory, but something completely independent. A directory is nothing but a collections of links to files (this is, why the syscall to remove a file from a directory is `unlink()`). When there are no links to a file (the `refcount` is zero), the file itself dies.

This has a few implications:

- One and the same file can perfectly well exist in more than one directory on a file system
- **Your question**: Deleting a file (or a subdirectory) from a directory (removing a link to it) or creating a link to it is not  an operation on the file, but on the directory. This implies, that the permissions of the file are irrelevant, it is the permissions of the directory, that count.

Comment: I still don't understand why `testdir` can be removed from the user-owned directory but `testdir/childdir` cannot be.  If the user has write access to the directory, then why can't they unlink `testdir/childdir` from it?

Comment: The user has no write privileges on `testdir`- so he can't remove anything (including `testdir/childdir`) from it. The user does have write privileges to his home directory, so he can remove `testdir` from it, which will obviously make everything below inaccessable.

Comment: Yes - but why does the user have to remove `childdir` from `testdir` first before they can remove `testdir` from their home directory?

Comment: You can't remove a link to a non-empty directory. This has nothing to do with privileges, even root can't `rmdir` a non-empty dir.

Comment: Fancy.  Seems good.